# MySQL - Retrieve the max value of an associated column within a LEFT JOIN with a different perimeter than the WHERE clause of the main query

Tags: mysql, sql, max, mysql-5.6

I'm using **MySql 5.6** and have a select query with a LEFT JOIN but i need to retrieve the max of a associated column `email_nb`) but with a different "perimeter" of constraints.

Let's take an example: let me state that it is a mere example with only 5 rows but it should work also when I have thousands... (I'm stating this since there is a `LIMIT` clause in my query)

**Table 'query_results'**

```
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+
| query_result_id             | query_id   | author       |
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+
| 2                           |         1  | john         |
| 3                           |         1  | eric         |
| 7                           |         3  | martha       |
| 9                           |         4  | john         |
| 10                          |         1  | john         |
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+
```

**Table 'customers_emails'**

```
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------
| customer_email_id | query_result_id | customer_id  | author    |  email_nb   | days_since_sending
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+------------------------
| 5                 |         2       | 12           |  john     |   2         |  150
| 12                |         3       | 7            |  eric     |   4         |  90
| 27                |         3       | 12           |  eric     |   2         |  86
| 40                |         9       | 15           |  john     |   9         |  87
| 42                |         2       | 12           |  john     |   7         |  23
| 51                |         10      | 12           |  john     |   3         |  89
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------------
```

**Notes:**

- you can have a `query_result` where the author appears in NO row at all in any of the `customers_emails`, hence the `LEFT JOIN` I'm using.
- You can see `author` is by design kind of duplicated as it's both on the first table and the second table each time associated with a `query_result_id`. It's important to note.
- `email_nb` is an integer between 0 and 10
- there is a `LIMIT` clause as I need to retrieve a set number of records

Today my query aims at retrieving `query_results` with a certain number of conditions on The specificity is that I make sure to retrieve query_results with an `author` who does not appear in any `customer_email_id` where the `days_since_sending` would be less than 60 days: it means i check these `days_since_sending` not only within the records for this query, but **across all `customers_emails`** thanks to the subquery `NOT IN` (see below).

This is **my current query** for `customer_id = 12` and `query_id = 1`

```
  SELECT             
    qr.query_result_id,     
    qr.author,
  FROM
    query_results qr
  LEFT JOIN
    customers_emails ce
  ON
    qr.author = ce.author           
  WHERE
    qr.query_id = 1 AND
    qr.author IS NOT NULL            
      AND qr.author NOT IN (
        SELECT recipient
        FROM customers_emails
        WHERE               
          (
            customer_id = 12 AND
            ( days_since_sending >= 60) ) 
          )           
      )     
  # we don't take by coincidence/bad luck 2 query results with the same author
  GROUP BY
    qr.author
  ORDER BY 
    qr.query_result_id ASC
  LIMIT 
    20
```

This is the expected output:

```
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+
| query_result_id             | author     | email_nb     |  
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+
|        10                   |   john     |    7         |
|        3                    |   eric     |    2         |   
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+
```

**My challenge/difficulty today:**

- Notice on the 2nd line Eric is tied to `email_nb` `2` and not the max of all Eric's emails which could have been `4` if we had taken the max of `email_nb` across ALL messages to `author=eric`. but we stay within the limit of `customer_id = 12` so there's only one left with `email_nb = 2`
- Also notice that on the first line, the `email_nb` associated with `query_result = 10` is `7`, and not `3`, which could have been the case as `3` is what appears in table `customers_emails` on the last line.
- Indeed for emails to 'john' i had the choice between `email_nb` `2`, `7` and `3` but I take highest so it's `7` (even if this email is from more than 60 days ago !! This is very important and part of what I don't know how to do: the perimeters are different: today I retrieve all the query_results where the `author` has NOT been sent a email for the past 60 days (see the `NOT IN` subquery) BUT I need to have in the column the max `email_nb` sent to `john` by `customer_id=12` and `query_id=1` EVEN if it was sent more than 60 days ago so these are different perimeters...Don't really know how to do this...
- It means in other words I don't want to find the max (email_nb) within the same `WHERE` clauses such as `days_since_sending >= 60` or within the same LIMIT and GROUP BY...as my current query: what I neeed is to retrieve the maximum value of `email_nb` for `customer_id=12` AND `query_id=1` and sent to `john` across **ALL records on the `customers_emails` table!**
- If there is no associated row on customers_emails at all (it means no email have been ever sent by this customer for this query in the past) then the email_nb should be sth like NULL..

This means I do NOT want this output:

```
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+
| query_result_id             | author     | email_nb     |  
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+
|        10                   |   john     |    3         |
|        3                    |   eric     |    2         |   
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+
```

How to achieve this in MySQL 5.6 ?

Comment: Too much information IMHO.  You may want to edit your question and instead just show us sample input, the expected output, and a _brief_ description of the logic involved.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do those: i give input , expected output and even "not expected" out put if challenge of the need i have is not fully understood. I know it's a lot but if I don't explain well the intricacies I fear that I will get false positive responses...

Comment: am trying to reduce the infos

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to do in a situation like this is break it down into smaller queries and then combine them together.

The first thing you want to do is this:

> The specificity is that I make sure to retrieve query_results with an author who does not appear in any customer_email_id where the days_since_sending would be less than 60 days

This might look something like this:

```
-- Query A
SELECT DISTINCT q.author FROM query_results q
WHERE q.author NOT IN (
    SELECT c.author FROM customers_emails c
    WHERE c.days_since_sending < 60
)
AND q.query_id = 1
```

This will get you the list of authors (with duplicates removed) that haven't had an email in the last 60 days that appear for the given query ID. Your next requirement is the following:

> I need to have in the column the max email_nb sent to john by customer_id=12 and query_id=1 EVEN if it was sent more than 60 days ago

This query could look like this:

```
-- Query B
SELECT c.query_result_id, c.author, MAX(c.email_nb) as max_email_nb
FROM customers_emails c
LEFT JOIN query_results q ON c.author = q.author
WHERE c.customer_id = 12
AND q.query_id = 1
GROUP BY c.query_result_id, c.author
```

That gets you the maximum email_nb for each author/query_result combination, not taking into consideration the date at all.

The only thing left to do is reduce the set of results from the second query down to only the authors that appear in the first query. There are a few different methods for doing that. For example, you could INNER JOIN the two queries by `author`:

```
SELECT b.* FROM (
    -- Query B
    SELECT c.query_result_id, c.author, MAX(c.email_nb) as max_email_nb
    FROM customers_emails c
    LEFT JOIN query_results q ON c.author = q.author
    WHERE c.customer_id = 12
    AND q.query_id = 1
    GROUP BY c.query_result_id, c.author
) b INNER JOIN (
    -- Query A
    SELECT DISTINCT q.author FROM query_results q
    WHERE q.author NOT IN (
        SELECT c.author FROM customers_emails c
        WHERE c.days_since_sending < 60
    )
    AND q.query_id = 1
) a ON a.author = b.author
```

You could use another NOT IN clause:

```
SELECT b.* FROM (
    -- Query B
    SELECT c.query_result_id, c.author, MAX(c.email_nb) as max_email_nb
    FROM customers_emails c
    LEFT JOIN query_results q ON c.author = q.author
    WHERE c.customer_id = 12
    AND q.query_id = 1
    GROUP BY c.query_result_id, c.author
) b
WHERE b.author NOT IN (
    -- Query A
    SELECT DISTINCT q.author FROM query_results q
    WHERE q.author NOT IN (
        SELECT c.author FROM customers_emails c
        WHERE c.days_since_sending < 60
    )
    AND q.query_id = 1
) a
```

There are most likely ways to improve the speed or reduce down the lines of code for this query, but if you need to do that you now have a query that works at least that you can compare the results to.

Comment: thanks! I'll try but I'm not a SQL expert...but on the first block where you do query B, you group by query_result_id, the fact you have max(c.email_nb), does that mean that only customers_emails rows where we have a high email_nb will be considered when implementing Query A? As explained, if you look at the expected output, you see a line query_result_id =10, author=john, that means even though this query_result_id had only 3 as email_nb (less than other for the same query and author), it should be in the results. anyway, I'll try now to check if it works

Comment: Hi - since the two queries are separate sub-queries, their results should not be affected by each other until you do either the INNER JOIN or the NOT IN on the outside of the query. Let me know if I have misunderstood your requirements though.

Comment: Note that contrary to me you left join on query B on c.query_result_id = q.query_result_id, but you can have different query_result_id with the same author, so I think i should keep on left joining on author as I was doing

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, that was an error. I will update the answer.

Comment: Removed also the group by c.query_result_id as i am OK to retrieve multiple similar query_result_id. the only group by is on authors

Comment: I think you are going to hit problems there, because if the query only groups on author then SQL will have to pick which query_result_id to display, which might cause an error depending on your version. Do you want the max email_nb over the author, or for each query_result linked to the author?

Comment: Having doubts about something but maybe same explanation as your first comment: what about if an author is inside a query_result but has never been emailed: he won't be at all inside customers_emails...but the query_result with this author should still be selected. The way you organized your query where I feel (as a sql rookie:) that you start by selecting stuff from <customers_emails with a join to query_results> on query B and not from <query_results with a join to customers_emails > (as i did) which is the opposite, make me feel this query_result will never be selected...

Comment: Ok, the NOT IN approach should still work though, because authors that don't appear in customers_emails won't be in the results of the second query.

Comment: "then SQL will have to pick which query_result_id to display, which might cause an error depending on your version": very true: among all possible, i want sql to pick any that comply with the constraints (for example that last sending should be <60 days if it's from this customer_id 12) but i just thought i can add a condition : retrieve all query_results (for given customer_id and query_id) where the author has been AT MAXIMUM been emailed for this query by this customer with email_nb = 7=> max (email_nb) < 7...

Comment: maybe i misunderstand but "Ok, the NOT IN approach should still work though, because authors that don't appear in customers_emails won't be in the results of the second query." is not what I need: let's say we have a query_result with author john. and NO customer_emails ever sent to author 'john': I DO want this query_result inside my final results

Comment: you removed my order_by and limit 20, on which part (query A or B?) should i put them?

Comment: So the NOT IN query in summary says, "get me every from query B where the author does not appear in query A". I'm saying that the author will not appear in query A because it doesn't exist in the customer_emails table, so therefore it *will* appear in the final results.

Comment: ho ok got it! intertesting

Comment: The ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses should be added to the outermost query, so right at the end of the whole thing.

Comment: No, the whole thing, so after the line reading `) a` in the case of the NOT IN version.

Comment: ok, i'll try but i'm surprised i can say group by q.author_email at this very end, i thought sql would not know what's the q. at that place as q naming is defined inside more "nested" places above

Comment: I'm talking about ORDER BY and LIMIT rather than GROUP BY. At the end of the query put `ORDER BY b.query_result_id LIMIT 10`. If you need a GROUP BY there as well, just precede column names with `b.` as that's the table alias you're getting the fields from.

Comment: It never worked: strange...my question was "hey i manage to get query_results" with my current query, but i just want to add a new column to this output called max_email_nb  so i know it's not working because at least i was getting results on my query, now it's totally empty... to be fair it was as one of the commenter said too much info. I changed and asked it in a cleaner way here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135341/mysql-cant-retrieve-max-value-within-a-left-join-and-2-distinct-select-perime

Answer (score 0):

Since you were confusing a bit, I came up on this.

```
select 
max(q.query_result_id) as query_result_id,q.author,max(email_nb) as email_nb
from query_results q
left join customers_emails c on q.author=c.author
where customer_id=12 and query_id=1
group by q.author;
```