# MySQL - can't retrieve max value within a left join and 2 distinct select perimeters

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I'm using **MySql 5.6** and I have 2 tables (simplified them to reduce nb of columns to what matters for this question) with a query that is using today a LEFT JOIN to Select rows.

Here is the fiddle to test your solution: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGVFhr3xMwKk9CDw6N6FWc/13

**Table 'query_results'**

```
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+-----------
| query_result_id             | query_id   | author       |  datecol
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+-----------
| 100                         |         1  | john         |   80
| 101                         |         1  | eric         |   70
| 102                         |         2  | emily        |   100
| 103                         |         2  | emily        |   100
| 104                         |         4  | emily        |   120
| 105                         |         3  | emily        |   50
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+-----------
```

**Table 'customers_emails'**

```
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| customer_email_id | query_result_id | customer_id  | author    |  email_nb 
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| 5                 |         758     | 12           |  mathew   |   0  
| 12                |         102     | 12           |  emily    |   0     
| 13                |         103     | 12           |  emily    |   1
| 14                |         104     | 12           |  emily    |   9
| 15                |         102     | 7            |  emily    |   2
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
```

My current query successfully fetches all the query_results for a given `query_id = 2` and a given `customer_id = 12` and some other minor constraints (such as datecol > 30).

```
  SELECT            
    qr.query_result_id,
    qr.query_id,
    qr.author
  FROM
    query_results qr
  LEFT JOIN
    customers_emails coe
  ON
    qr.author = coe.author AND
    coe.customer_id = 12           
  WHERE        
    qr.query_id = 2 AND
    qr.datecol >= 30 AND
    qr.author IS NOT NULL            
      AND qr.author NOT IN (
        SELECT author
        FROM customers_emails
        WHERE 
          (
            customer_id = 12 AND
            email_nb = 3
          )
      )
  GROUP BY
    qr.author
  ORDER BY 
    qr.query_result_id ASC
  LIMIT 
    2
```

This query above works perfectly (I'm satisfied) and gives me:

Today My output is :

```
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+
| query_result_id   | query_id        | author       | 
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+
| 102               |         2       | emily        |                 
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

Now my goal and where I fail is: I simply want to **add a new column called max_email_nb** to the current output which would be **"the highest `email_nb` sent

- by the given `customer_id` (=12)
- on this given `query_id` (=2)
- to each line's `author` from the current SQL output, in the example above it's `emily` (but there could be more lines and can't be predicted: it comes from the current query!)**

I tried to use MAX():

```
      SELECT            
        qr.query_result_id,
        qr.query_id,
        qr.author,
        MAX(coe.email_nb) as max_email_nb
      FROM
        query_results qr
      LEFT JOIN
        customers_emails coe
      ON
        qr.author = coe.author AND
        coe.customer_id = 12           
      WHERE        
        qr.query_id = 2 AND
        qr.datecol >= 30 AND
        qr.author IS NOT NULL            
          AND qr.author NOT IN (
            SELECT author
            FROM customers_emails
            WHERE 
              (
                customer_id = 12 AND
                email_nb = 3
              )
          )
      GROUP BY
        qr.author
      ORDER BY 
        qr.query_result_id ASC
      LIMIT 
        2
```

Today My output is :

```
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------
| query_result_id   | query_id        | author       |  max_email_nb   | ... 
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+------------
| 102               |         2       | emily        |  9              |                
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+------------
```

**The value in max_email_nb is incorrect** : based on what I aim to do, I expect  the value of max_email_nb to be equal to `1` instead of `9`. The output I expect is:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-------------
| query_result_id   | query_id        | author       |  max_email_nb   | ... 
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+------------
| 102               |         2       | emily        |  1              |                
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+------------
```

Indeed I want to retrieve for each `query_result` that is outputted by my SQL query, the highest email_nb sent by a `given Customer_id 12` on `query_id 2` to this `author` (in this specific line coming from the current SQL query it's `emily`).

So where does this incorrect 9 value come from ? It comes from from this input line:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| customer_email_id | query_result_id | customer_id  | author    |  email_nb   | 
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| 14                |         104     | 12           |  emily    |   9
```

... so it's associated with `query_result_id= 104`, which itself is defined here:

```
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+-----------
| query_result_id             | query_id   | author       |  datecol
+-----------------------------+------------+--------------+-----------
| 104                         |         4  | emily        |   120
```

...so it's with `query_id = 4` ! But as I said when defining what my goal was that I was looking for sth associated with `query_id = 2` , that's why I should not get `9` but the value `1`!

Here is a fiddle to test your solution: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGVFhr3xMwKk9CDw6N6FWc/13

I tried subqueries, I tried inner joins...but nothing works.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200105/discussion-on-question-by-mathieu-mysql-cant-retrieve-max-value-within-a-left).

Comment: Check the fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=848f58e359092ea968c689a5fbfbd028

Comment: @AnkitBajpai i'll do thanks

Comment: "*This query above works perfectly*" - No! That query is **non-deterministic**, due to a wrong use of GROUP BY. If it returns the expected result, then you've just been "lucky". See in [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4EWDPb54HmKhAFqRqFZjUn/0), how irrelevant changes can lead to a different result. You don't explain anywhere, why `query_result_id` should be `102` and not `103`. Asking for any solution based on this query doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Hi @PaulSpiegel i made a lot of checks and it does work on mysql 5.6. It seems there was an issue with group by and my sql changed sth for this after 5.7...maybe that's what you are talking about ? I'll read now your fiddle.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel because for me it is irrelevant at this stage

Comment: Well, you've received three answers with the same solution. And you claim they don't work. But they only don't work in cases, where your "perfect" query neither does work. So I'd say - **It is unclear what you are asking**. Again.. At least three users (those who wrote the answers), thought they understood your question. But it seams, they were wrong.

Comment: Each time I've provided clear db-fiddle example on what was the issue. One person answered it with success: bhuvnesh pattnaik, to whom I will give the points as soon as SO allows it (18 hours from now)

Comment: It doesn't matter if someone has solved your problems. Unclear questions should be improved or closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on fiddle and it worked like charm,

You can also try this.

```
SELECT            
    qr.query_result_id,
    qr.query_id,    
    qr.author,
    MAX(coe.email_nb) as max_email_nb
  FROM
    query_results qr
  LEFT JOIN
    customers_emails coe
  ON
    qr.author = coe.author  
    and coe.customer_id = 12
    and qr.query_result_id = coe.query_result_id
  WHERE 
    qr.query_id = 2 AND
    qr.datecol >= 30 AND
    qr.author IS NOT NULL            
      AND qr.query_result_id NOT IN (
        SELECT query_result_id
        FROM customers_emails
        WHERE 
          (
            customer_id = 12 AND
            email_nb = 3
          )
      )
  GROUP BY
    qr.author
  ORDER BY 
    qr.query_result_id ASC
  LIMIT 
    20
```

Comment: Hi bhuvnesh: same comment as for Sergey: Your suggestion to be fair is almost 100% correct..I tried a bunch of cases and it always works...one case where it's not working is https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGVFhr3xMwKk9CDw6N6FWc/15 where I set email_nb= 3 on customer_email_id=13 because it conflicts with WHERE clause "not in ...email_nb =3". It should have fallen back on another query_result and give me the value 0 coming from VALUES(12, 102, 12, 'emily', 0);

Comment: Hi @Mathieu, Thank you for the suggestion, I havve updated my answer, Please check

Comment: i'll make final checks but i think this is CORRECt ! the big "trick" was that you replaced  AND qr.author NOT IN  by AND qr.query_result_id NOT IN (, feels the right approach

Comment: yes it was corretc and i'll give the points in 19 hours, which  is only then that SO allows bounty points

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing a clause in `ON` statement. Would this work?

```
  SELECT            
    qr.query_result_id,
    qr.query_id,
    qr.author,
    MAX(coe.email_nb) as max_email_nb
  FROM
    query_results qr
  LEFT JOIN
    customers_emails coe
  ON
    qr.author = coe.author AND
    qr.query_result_id = coe.query_result_id
  WHERE        
    qr.query_id = 2 AND
    qr.datecol >= 30 AND
    qr.author IS NOT NULL            
      AND qr.author NOT IN (
        SELECT author
        FROM customers_emails
        WHERE 
          (
            customer_id = 12 AND
            email_nb = 3
          )
      )
  GROUP BY
    qr.author
  ORDER BY 
    qr.query_result_id ASC
  LIMIT 
    2
```

Comment: UPD: I've read the discussion in chat, looks like I was wrong with my suggestion. Thinking on how to rewrite it.

Comment: Let me try on my fiddle

Comment: let me digest/make sure it does: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGVFhr3xMwKk9CDw6N6FWc/14

Comment: I don't think the query is correct, because logic based on LIMIT or TOP is not deterministic.

Comment: almost worked: but look https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGVFhr3xMwKk9CDw6N6FWc/15... I should get a result with max_email_nb = 0 coming from VALUES(12, 102, 12, 'emily', 0); but the result output is empty. It's due to the NOT IN email_nb=3 i think

Comment: @Mathieu Well, one problem with your query was definitely in this `ON` clause - in your example the query before filtering and grouping was giving you a set of rows that included all possible combinations of rows based on author only, e.g. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ufH2zUdAsz37MDdqH4y7Pd/1

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev you're right, it feels like this.

Comment: Your suggesiton to be fair is almost 100% correct..I tried a bunch of cases and it always works...one case where it's not working is https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGVFhr3xMwKk9CDw6N6FWc/15 where I set email_nb= 3 on customer_email_id=13 because it conflicts with WHERE clause "not in "

Comment: @Mathieu RE: `I should get a result with max_email_nb = 0 coming from VALUES(12, 102, 12, 'emily', 0); but the result output is empty.` - this result is filtered out by `AND qr.author NOT IN ...` clause

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev no: the result filtered out is the one where email_nb=3 but VALUES(12, 102, 12, 'emily', 0) has email_nb=0 so it should not be filtered out by the NOT IN clause. Am I wrong ? The NOT IN clause filters out any result where customer_id=12 and email_nb= 3 but email_nb= 0 should NOt be filtered out

Comment: @Mathieu The query `        SELECT author
        FROM customers_emails
        WHERE 
          (
            customer_id = 12 AND
            email_nb = 3
          )` is giving you a result `emily`. So your `AND qr.author NOT IN ...` clause effectively turns into `AND qr.author NOT IN ('emily')`, which would filter out any results with author `emily`.

Comment: @Mathieu Looks like you wanted to set `customer_id` to 13 in this filter and put 12 instead?..

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev I'm not sure to understand/gree: look here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGVFhr3xMwKk9CDw6N6FWc/16 ...it'(s giving me Emily but the NOT IN i snot filtering it out...it's not about havingh emily, it' s just that here i removed the email_nb=3 to put email_nb = 2

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev no i want query_id=2 and customer_id=12

Comment: Let me explain I want all query_results with query_id=2 where the query_result's author has either never been emailed by customer_id=12 (that's the easy case hehe/it's working i checked) or if he's been emailed already by customer_id=12, then the email should not be email_nb=3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200150/discussion-between-sergey-kudriavtsev-and-mathieu).

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want, without the non-deterministic `LIMIT` logic.

```
SELECT            
    qr.query_result_id,
    qr.query_id,
    qr.author,
    MAX(coe.email_nb)
  FROM
    query_results qr
  LEFT JOIN
    customers_emails coe
  ON
    qr.author = coe.author AND
    qr.query_result_id = coe.query_result_id AND
    coe.customer_id = 12      
  WHERE        
    qr.query_id = 2 AND
    qr.datecol >= 30 AND
    qr.author IS NOT NULL            
      AND qr.query_result_id NOT IN (
        SELECT query_result_id
        FROM customers_emails
        WHERE 
          (
            customer_id = 12 AND
            email_nb = 3
          )
      )
  ORDER BY 
    qr.query_result_id ASC
```

You can have a look at the [Fiddle result](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGVFhr3xMwKk9CDw6N6FWc/13).

[image]

---

**Additional info:**

The reason for why you had a `9` instead of a `1` was because your `LEFT JOIN` condition was not sufficient.

You only joined by matching `AUTHOR` in both columns, but `emily` has also a entry with a `email_nb` equal to `9`.

In order to get the correct result, you also had to join based on `QUERY_RESULT_ID` in order to limit `emily` to only query results that are `102`.

Comment: thanks. your link was not working but i copy pasted your answer here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGVFhr3xMwKk9CDw6N6FWc/21 it does work. BUT same as for @Sergey: if i put the email_nb to 3 in `VALUES(13, 103, 12, 'emily', 3)`, then no result at all --> see https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nGVFhr3xMwKk9CDw6N6FWc/22. I should be getting max_email_nb= 0 coming from this line `VALUES(12, 102, 12, 'emily', 0);` !

Comment: @Mathieu ok, it seems like you're actually considering the `query_result_id` into the question. How about my modified answer?